MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/
I run my application on android device and every thing seem to be fine but when i run the app on ios simulator  i got this issue for every package i am not familiar with ios installation can you help?
here is the code where i got the problem
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((value) {
    AppInfoHelper.packageInfo = value;
  });
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.iosProduction);

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
  handleForeGroundNotification();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  // FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(onNotificationOpenApp);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized(

  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: kMainDarkColor, // status bar color
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light, // status bar icons' color
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      systemNavigationBarColor: kBackGroundColor));

  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en'), Locale('ar')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      startLocale: const Locale('ar'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      child: MyApp(appRouter: AppRouter()),
    ),
  );
}

this is the line that caused the issue
 await PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((value) {
    AppInfoHelper.packageInfo = value;
  });

when i replace this line with firebase line i got the same issue for firebase
my xode verison xcode-select version 2405.
and this is the yaml file name:
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 4.2.1+73

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1
  web_socket_channel: ^3.0.1
  http: ^1.2.2
  carousel_slider: ^5.0.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  animations: ^2.0.5
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  pinput: ^5.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^15.0.4
  shimmer_animation: ^2.1.0+1
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  flutter_datetime_picker_plus: ^2.0.1
  photo_view: ^0.15.0
  badges: ^3.1.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  package_info_plus: ^8.0.2
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  share_plus: ^10.0.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.2
  phone_number: ^2.1.0
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  keyboard_actions: ^4.2.0
  app_links: ^6.3.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  flutter_exit_app: ^1.1.2
  shimmer: ^3.0.0

  facebook_app_events:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events
      ref: fix/iOS-issue-0.19.4


  cached_network_image:




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/translations/
  fonts:
    - family: CairoR
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CAIRO-REGULAR.OTF
    - family: CairoL
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CAIRO-LIGHT.OTF
    - family: CairoB
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CAIRO-BOLD2.TTF
  uses-material-design: true


Where exactly is the line of code that causes the problem? If there is a crash, please provide a stack trace. Also, please include what version of Xcode you are using and your pubspec.yaml file.

when i switch lines with firebase this is what i got  Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

What do you mean, when I switch lines?
